# "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined" even though it's already defined

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, discord.js, ytdl

I'm making a Discord music Bot and I'm having trouble with an error saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

I tried console logging it and it showed me the `url`, so I don't understand what is the problem with my code.

Here's my code:

```
//musicBOT
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const mcPrefix = '.';

const queue = new Map();

client.on('ready', () => console.log('Music bot ready!'));

client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(mcPrefix)) return;

    const args = message.content.substring(mcPrefix.length).split(" ");
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

    if(message.content.startsWith(`${mcPrefix}play`)) {

        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if(!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("Hang-szobában kell lenned zenelejátszáshoz.");
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if(!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send("Nincs jogosultságom csatlakozni a hangszobához.");
        if(!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send("Nincs jogosultságom megszólalni ebben a hangszobában.");

        const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1])
        const song = {
            title: songInfo.title,
            url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url
        }

        if(!serverQueue) {
            const queueConstruct = {
                textChannel: message.channel,
                voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
                connection: null,
                songs: [],
                volume: 5,
                playing: true
            }
            queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct)

            queueConstruct.songs.push(song)

            try{
                var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
                message.channel.send(`${song.title} lejátszása.`)
                queueConstruct.connection = connection
                play(message.guild, queueConstruct.songs[0])
            }catch(e){
                console.log(`Hiba csatlakozás közben itt: ${e}`);
                queue.delete(message.guild.id)
                return message.channel.send(`Hiba volt a csatlakozás közben itt: ${e}`)
            }
        } else{
            serverQueue.songs.push(song)
            return message.channel.send(`**${song.title}** hozzáadva a lejátszási listához.`)
        }
        return undefined
        

        
    }else if (message.content.startsWith(`${mcPrefix}stop`)) {
        if(!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send("Hang-szobában kell lenned ahhoz, hogy leállítsd a zenét.")
        if(!serverQueue) return message.channel.send("There is nothing playing")
        serverQueue.songs= []
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end()
        message.channel.send("Sikeresen megálltottad a zenét.")
        return undefined
    }else if(message.content.startsWith(`${mcPrefix}skip`)){
        if(!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send("Hang-szobában kell lenned a skip parancshoz.")
        if(!serverQueue) return message.channel.send("There is nothing playing")
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end()
        message.channel.send("Zene továbbléptetve.")
        message.channel.send(`${song.title} játszása.`)
        
        return undefined
    }

    function play(guild, song) {
        const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id)
    
        if(!serverQueue.songs){
            serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave()
            queue.delete(guild.id)
            return
        }
    
        const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url))
            .on('finish', () => {
                serverQueue.songs.shift()
                play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0])
            })
            .on('error', error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
            dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5)
    }

})
//musicBOT
```

and here is the full error:

```
const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(songInfo.url))
                                                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
    at play (C:\Users\Levi\Desktop\Discord BOT Javascript\bot.js:97:70)
    at StreamDispatcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Levi\Desktop\Discord BOT Javascript\bot.js:100:17)
    at StreamDispatcher.emit (node:events:388:22)
    at finish (node:internal/streams/writable:734:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
```

I started searching on the internet but found nothing about it, I guess my basic javascript knowledge is just not enough.

Comment: Did you check that `song` is defined on play function?

Comment: Just checked it, and it is defined.

Comment: based on your error, the `song` is undefined in `const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(songInfo.url))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty `songs` array checking in `play` function is incorrect:

```
// This "if" clause will never be run, voice channel won't leave when there's no song
if(!serverQueue.songs){
  serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave()
  ...
}
```

Fix:

```
if(serverQueue.songs.length === 0){
  ...
}
```